# Why does my flask server stop and waits till i give a keyboard input?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, server

My python flask server ehich is running on my Windows server keeps stopping. That means it doesnt give a response till i press a bujtton in the command prompt. But sometimes it works fine for an hour or more and after i pressed a button it often works fine too for an hour.

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify
import json
import requests
from json import JSONEncoder
import numpy
import logging

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1/admin/login', methods=['GET'])
def api_Admin_User():
    
    if comparePassword(request.args.get('username'), request.args.get('password')):
        logging.info("admin login successful for " + request.args.get('username'))
        return jsonify({"success": True})
    else:
        logging.warning("admin login failed for \"" + request.args.get('username') + "\" with password \"" + request.args.get('password') + "\" and IP \"" + request.remote_addr + "\"")
        return jsonify({"success": False})

def comparePassword(username, password):
    jsonFile = open("admin.json", "r") # Open the JSON file for reading
    data = json.load(jsonFile) # Read the JSON into the buffer
    jsonFile.close() # Close the JSON file
    logging.info("comparing password for " + username)
    if data[username.lower()]["password"] == password:
        return True
    else:
        return False

from waitress import serve
serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)# ssl_context=context
```

Comment: Do you mean that you're only ever using or testing the /api/v1/admin/login route when this happens?

Comment: yes but this also happens when i use another route i only showed this

Comment: Is there anything else in your definition of `app` than `Flask(name)`? Any middleware? It looks like you might have tried to guess which parts of your code we needed. Instead, your steps should be (1) cut down your code to the parts that cause the error, (2) run the cut down code itself to see if it still causes the error, and if it does (3) post the code here that causes the error, if you can't figure out your problem yourself. For more reading on how to do this, see [MCVE].

Comment: sorry i forgot one line. this code still "holds" sometimes until i press a key

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `app.run()` instead of `serve()`? Otherwise, what is the reason to use `serve()`?

Let me make some improvements to your code:

```py
import flask, json, requests, numpy, logging
from flask import request, jsonify
from json import JSONEncoder

# define comparePassword() before using Flask to avoid misundertandings/conflicts
#   by/with it
def comparePassword(username, password):
    jsonFile = open("admin.json", "r") # Open the JSON file for reading
    data = json.load(jsonFile) # Read the JSON into the buffer
    jsonFile.close() # Close the JSON file
    logging.info("comparing password for " + username)
    if data[username.lower()]["password"] == password:
        return True
    else:
        return False

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1/admin/login', methods=['GET'])
def api_Admin_User():
    
    if comparePassword(request.args.get('username'), request.args.get('password')):
        logging.info("admin login successful for " + request.args.get('username'))
        return jsonify({"success": True})
    else:
        logging.warning("admin login failed for \"" + request.args.get('username') + "\" with password \"" + request.args.get('password') + "\" and IP \"" + request.remote_addr + "\"")
        return jsonify({"success": False})

# ditch waitress.serve
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000) # ssl_context=context
```

Comment: the thing is i wanna use a production server. but i resolved the issue by changing to uvicorn

Comment: @YouAreBamboozled `app.run()` should also work for production servers

Comment: I know thats what i did. Didnt i wrote that up there?

Comment: @YouAreBamboozled nope [you didnt](https://i.imgur.com/idEuVzF.png)